# how to get form parameters after post request sent with jQuery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form

```js
$("#mainform").submit(function() {
  $.post($("#mainform").attr("action"), $("#mainform").serialize(), function(data){
    doSomething();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="mainform">
  <input type="hidden" name="myparam" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

How can I get the parameters sent with the form, like "myparam" in this example? Looks like the 'data' parameter of the callback function rather returns the html of the whole page.

Comment: What's being returned in the callback is the data being sent from the other side (where your POST went to). If you need to do something with the data POSTed, you should go to this end.

Comment: in .attr("action"), where have you mentioned the action value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` will return the whole page indeed. That's what the function does.

What you want to do is

```
$("#mainform").submit();
```

the $.ajax() ($.get, $.post etc) are made to asynchronously submit the form, so the data variable in the callback will contain the response content (in your case the full page at the url you sent the form to)

Answer (score -1):

> Looks like the 'data' parameter of the callback function rather
>   returns the html of the whole page.

That is correct.

If you wanted to access elements of the form in the callback function, you should create a variable of your form element.

```
$("#mainform").submit(function() {
            var theForm = $("#mainform");
            $.post($("#mainform").attr("action"), $("#mainform").serialize(), function(data){
                var myparam = theform.find('input [name="myparam"]');
                doSomething();

            });
```